# How to create another field map in groovy?

Tags: groovy

I have this field map:

```
@Field
def images = [
        [name: 'image-1', shouldBuild: "false"],
        [name: 'image-2', shouldBuild: "false"],
        [name: 'image-3', shouldBuild: "false"]
]
```

And in a function, I'm checking if those image names are contained in a text file.

If any of the images are contained, I need to create a new field map containing only those specific images.

So, imagine that only image-1 is contained, I want the new field map to be (notice the change in shouldBuild to "true"):

```
@Field
def imagesChanged = [
        [name: 'image-1', shouldBuild: "true"]
]
```

This is what I have so far:

```
for (imageMap in images) {
    def shouldBuild = imageMap.get('shouldBuild')
    def image = imageMap.get('name')

    if (diff.any { el -> el.contains(image) }) {
      shouldBuild = "true"
    }
```

This is working to set shouldBuild to "true" in the images field, not in imagesChanged field. How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i assume `diff` is an array of valid image names

you just need to build new array with new maps

```
def images = [
        [name: 'image-1', shouldBuild: "false"],
        [name: 'image-2', shouldBuild: "false"],
        [name: 'image-3', shouldBuild: "false"]
]
def diff = ['image-2']

def imagesChanged = []
for (imageMap in images) {
    def image = imageMap.get('name')

    if (diff.any { el -> el.contains(image) }) {
      //imageMap + [shouldBuild: "true" ]  --> creates a new map with `shouldBuild` changed
      imagesChanged.add(imageMap + [shouldBuild: "true" ])
    }
}

println images
println imagesChanged
```

fyi: it's possible to do this code more groovy

```
def images = [
        [name: 'image-1', shouldBuild: "false"],
        [name: 'image-2', shouldBuild: "false"],
        [name: 'image-3', shouldBuild: "false"]
]
def diff = ['image-2']

def imagesChanged = images.findAll{ i-> i.name in diff }.collect{ i->
    i+[shouldBuild:"true"]
}

println images
println imagesChanged
```

Comment: proper one-liner `images.findResults{ i-> ( i.name in diff ) ? i+[shouldBuild:"true"] : null }`